# Fontawesome with LaTeX

Tags: fontawesome

I'm trying to use the package `fontawesome` with LaTeX, since the documentation says *"This package works both with XƎ(LA)TEX and Lua(LA)TEX (using fontspec
to load the included original otf font), **as well as (pdf)(LA)TEX** (using an
included type1 conversion and character mapping of the font)."*

The point is that, after installing the package, I get an error when I try to compile:

```
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
!
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
!
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
```

What should I do to be able to use the symbols the package gives?

Thanks in advance.

**Minimal example:** This is enough to get the error.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
Hi \faMale

\end{document}
```

In addition, I got the package from `texlive-fonts-extra`.

Using TexMaker 4.1 and TeX Live 2013.20140215-1

Comment: Don't load `fontspec`, if you want to use `pdflatex`

Comment: @egreg I don't load `fontspec` and I still get the error.

Comment: Please, add a minimal example, but maybe you have the same problem as in the question I linked, that is, an outdated version of `fontawesome.sty` hanging somewhere. Also report the line in the log where `fontawesome.sty` is loaded.

Comment: Then post a small example that gives you problem. Although it's weird because `fontawesome` doesn't require `xelatex` or `lualatex`.

Comment: @egreg I read that thread, but I'm afraid it is unuseful for me since I use TeX Live instead of MikTeX.

Comment: [Your code works fine with me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QLsdo.png), apart from a warning about the option `openright` being unused, but that's it.

Comment: You don't have an older version of `fontawesome`? Add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass` and you'll get a pretty-printed list of packages and their versions near the end of the `.log` file. Also look at the log to see exactly where `fontawesome.sty` is located, to make sure it is not some stray copy.

Comment: So you have an old version of TeX Live and hence an old version of `fontawesome`, likely from before the `pdflatex` compatibility was added.

Comment: `pdflatex` support was added in version 4.3.0, which was released on July 9, 2015: https://github.com/xdanaux/fontawesome-latex/releases

Comment: I get `(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty
Package: fontawesome 2013/05/10 v3.1.1 font awesome icons` in the log file. I will upgradeTeXLive, but I suposse I must download it from the website, as the lastest available version in Synaptic is that, mustn't I?

Comment: Of course, you can't think that, when the current version of TeX Live is 2016, with the 2013 release you can have all the bells and whistles. Upgrade your TeX Live.

Comment: I usually install TeX Live using the installer from TUG.org, see [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373) for instructions. While `apt-get install texlive-full` might be easier, it's also usually older, and you can't use `tlmgr` to update packages.

Comment: Thank you guys, it works now. But now I have the problem that `tikz-cd` has just stopped working (`tikz` works). I will try to fix the other problem now.